# FreeBSD with nginx can't connect networks after running for a while

Tags: nginx, freebsd

My server is a FreeBSD system, I run nginx on it to proxy user requests to another real server. 
   My problem is I can't visit my freebsd server after a while. The server is in another place, so I have to go to fix it. When the problem happens, the server can't ping another address, it can't use networks, if I reboot it and restart nginx, everything becomes normal.
But after a while, it can't be visited again.
  I am not quite familiar with freebsd, so anyone can't help to find out the possible reason?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's problem with mbufs count. 
There is 2 possible solutions:

- Use my [FreeBSD sysctl tuning guide](https://serverfault.com/questions/64356/freebsd-configuration-sysctl-tuning)
- Update to 7.2 amd64 that is pretty
  tuned by default

You can easily check limits:
Compare values LIMIT and USED in `vmstat`

```
# vmstat -z
```

Comment: Do you mean the server has used out of all mbufs? I guess this will happen if we've too many visits, but our server is not visited by many  users(not more than 100 before it's down), and will mbufs be reused after a time, which means the server will recover after some time? Till now nothing changed actually.

Comment: mbufs, open files, somaxcon etc... there is too many limits in OS that you can bump in.

Answer (score 0):

Check the network card as well - it might be the mbufs issue that SaveTheRbtz mentions but I've also had this problem with a network card that would inexplicably 'wedge' after a while.

Comment: Yeah, that's might be good suggestion. Grep `/var/log/messages` for something like `watchdog time out` and other messages from your NICs' drivers

Answer (score 0):

Also check out your firewall, I had some problems with a server not forgetting about connections for a few hours. Eventually it would fill up its allotted connections and just reject everything else. If I waited it would come back. In the end I just had to disable connection tracking.

Comment: pf have state table that can overflow: use `pfctl -sa` and watch LIMITS