# Ierrs on Network Interface - Pfsense/Freebsd

Tags: networking, freebsd, ethernet, pfsense, netstat

We're using PfSense as an internal router/firewall (no connection to WAN).  Using the Web-GUI, under Status ---> Interfaces,  there's one particular interface where I have some errors:

```
In/out errors    3513/0
```

I then SSHed to the firewall to validate the info provided by the WebGUI and here's the output:

```
# netstat -ni -I bce2
Name    Mtu Network       Address                  Ipkts Ierrs     Opkt  Oerrs  Coll
bce2   1500 <Link#3>      00:23:7d:cd:a2:a2   1404522323  3513 749797131     0     0
bce2   1500 10.42.1.0/24  10.42.1.24                   6     -         6     -     -
```

As you can see, both present the same info (errors on incoming packets).  I switched cables, changed network card, changed port on switch and I still see the errors.  My 2 questions really are:

1) Is there any way I could get more info on the nature of these errors? or is this all I can get?

2) Should I be worried about this? As you can see, the errors are a VERY LOW percentage of all the total incoming packets.  In other words, is this normal on a high-traffic gigabit interface?

Thanks!
JFA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) There may be dosens of possible reasons. Most possible: you've got some buffer overruns.

Analyze:

- `dmesg`
- `sysctl dev.bce`
- `vmstat -z` (USED/LIMIT)
- `netstat -s` (Errors/Buffers)

You can also try some tuning described here: [FreeBSD performance tuning: Sysctl parameter, loader.conf, kernel](https://serverfault.com/questions/64356/freebsd-performance-tuning-sysctls-loader-conf-kernel)

But these are intended for advanced sysadmins only, use them on your own risk!

2) Maybe. With time, when the load increases this percentage will rise, too.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help. That's exactly what I needed to get started.  When I run the sysctl command I get: 
    
dev.bce.2.com_no_buffers: 3513

...so that indeed seems like a buffer overrun? I checked kern.ipc.nmbclusters but it is set to zero.  I'm still looking... Thanks!

Comment: now you have something to start googling =) good place to start is here: http://groups.google.com/group/mailing.freebsd.current/browse_thread/thread/9d6b64e45c64234e/d6fc4dc2eff2f038?lnk=raot&pli=1